# PHP strtotime generates different results

Tags: php, ubuntu, time, timezone, strtotime

I have 2 servers. They both using same os: Ubuntu 14.04 server + php-fpm. I can't make them to generate same `strtotime` results.

For date time: `2013-12-30 18:29:59`

First server's `strtotime` outputs: `1388431799`

Second server's `strtotime` outputs: `1388449799`

## What I've done

- I changed both server's OS timezone and did same - `UTC` time (without reboot)
- I changed both server's php timezone and made them same (then restarted php service)

Result still is not same? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Echo out each server's timezones and confirm they are indeed the same

Comment: @JohnConde if you mean OS time then yes

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you done it in PHP? `echo date_default_timezone_get();`?

Comment: @JohnConde they have difference in seconds. I felt this now. About 30-40 seconds diff

Comment: The difference is 5 hrs.

Comment: the difference is 18000, which means your servers have timezones that are 5 hours apart.

Comment: As I see now, strtotime is very unreliable. I used it in URL system of my blog-like web project. Website migration from first to second server ruined url's. Now server can't find needed blogpost

Comment: I think this article is relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/228/how-to-set-ubuntu-to-synchronize-my-clock-with-a-time-server -- whoa 5 hours? that has gotta be timezone.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the timezone like this since the difference is 5 hrs then they probably are having different timezones

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Also to note that `strtotime`  is quite picky.

Comment: He should rather set the timezone in the used php.ini.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois:- I am not sure if he is doing that for testing or what. Although I agree that it is also a valid place to make the change +1 :) Steps to change here:- http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-phpini-file